# Network behind another network - hardware required

Tags: networking, cisco, nat

We have a small team (4-5 people) in another company's office - they are happy for us to use their SDSL connection and give us an IP address, but apart from that we can't change any configuration on their network.

We would like to NAT/Firewall off our computers and if possible provide a VPN for all PCs back to our main office.  Don't care about Gigabit, WiFi, VLANS/Port forwarding etc.

Would a Cisco RV220 be enough or do we need to get something a bit better or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RV220 seems to be a capable device for your situation.  With only a handful of computers, nothing fancy is needed.

Regarding the VPN, it has support for IPSec site-to-site tunnels.  You seem to be covered, but it's dependent on what you have to integrate with at the main office.